# Modul basic not found

Tags: missing

I have some old documents wich I update every couple years. Today I wanted to update one from 2009. I get the error message module basic not found, so I tried to install it, since my machine isn't the one i used 2009. The problem is, I can't find the module. Not in my debian packages, not on the web. Where can I find the module basic?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I've never heard of a ‘basic’ module. Could you post the .log file?

Comment: that does not sound like a Tex error, please show the exact error that you got.

Comment: I'm using LyX, more datails later, when I have access to this machine

Comment: Problem solved! I removed my local config dir .lyx and now it works. So there must be sonthing wrong in the configuration!